# import inside of a Python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, locking, python-import

I have some functions that interactively load python modules using `__import__`

I recently stumbled upon some article about an "import lock" in Python, that is, a lock specifically for imports (not just the GIL). But the article was old so maybe that's not true anymore.

This makes me wonder about the practice of importing in a thread.

1. Are `import`/`__import__` thread safe?
2. Can they create dead locks?
3. Can they cause performance issues in a threaded application?

EDIT 12 Sept 2012

Thanks for the great reply Soravux.
So import are thread safe, and I'm not worrying about deadlocks, since the functions that use `__import__` in my code don't call each others.

Do you know if the lock is acquired even if the module has already been imported ?
If that is the case, I should probably look in sys.modules to check if the module has already been imported before making a call to `__import__`.

Sure this shouldn't make a lot of difference in CPython since there is the GIL anyway.
However it could make a lot of difference on other implementations like Jython or stackless python.

EDIT 19 Sept 2012

About Jython, here's what they say in the doc:

http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Concurrency.html#module-import-lock

> Python does, however, define a module import lock, which is
>   implemented by Jython. This lock is acquired whenever an import of any
>   name is made. This is true whether the import goes through the import
>   statement, the equivalent `__import__` builtin, or related code. It’s
>   important to note that even if the corresponding module has already
>   been imported, the module import lock will still be acquired, if only
>   briefly.

So, it seems that it would make sense to check in sys.modules before making an import, to avoid acquiring the lock. What do you think?

Comment: I'd imagine them to be thread safe, since as you say, the interpreter blocks on imports.  I'd be interested to find out if they could cause deadlocks in any way other than typical non-threaded circular imports.

Answer (score 19):

Update: Since Python 3.3, import locks are per-module instead of global, and `imp` is deprecated in favor of [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib). More information on the [changelog](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.3.html#a-finer-grained-import-lock) and [this issue ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue9260).

**The original answer below predates Python 3.3**

Normal imports are thread-safe because they acquire an import lock prior to execution and release it once the import is done. If you add your own custom imports using the hooks available, be sure to add this locking scheme to it. Locking facilities in Python may be accessed by the `imp` module (`imp.lock_held()`/`acquire_lock()`/`release_lock()`). **Edit:** This is deprecated since Python 3.3, no need to manually handle the lock.

Using this import lock won't create any deadlocks or dependency errors aside from the circular dependencies that are [already known](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) (module `a` imports module `b` which imports module `a`). **Edit:** Python 3.3 changed for a per-module locking mechanism to prevent those deadlocks caused by circular imports.

There exist multiple ways to create new processes or threads, for example [`fork`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [`clone`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/clone) (assuming a Linux environment). Each way yields different memory behaviors when creating the new process. By default, a fork copies most memory segments (Data (often COW), Stack, Code, Heap), effectively not sharing its content between the child and its parent. The result of a `clone` (often called a thread, this is what Python uses for threading) shares all memory segments with its parent except the stack. The import mechanism in Python uses the global namespace which is *not* placed on the stack, thus using a shared segment between its threads. This means that all memory modifications (except for the stack) performed by an `import` in a thread will be visible to all its other related threads and parent. If the imported module is Python-only, it is thread-safe by design. If an imported module uses non-Python libraries, make sure those are thread-safe, otherwise it **will** cause mayhem in your multithreaded Python code.

By the way, threaded programs in Python suffers the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) which won't allow much performance gains unless your program is I/O bound or rely on C or external thread-safe libraries (since they *should* release the GIL before executing). Running in two threads the same imported Python function won't execute concurrently because of this GIL. Note that this is only a limitation of CPython and other implementations of Python may have a different behavior.

To answer your edit: imported modules are all cached by Python. If the module is already loaded in the cache, it won't be run again and the import statement (or function) will return right away. You don't have to implement yourself the cache lookup in sys.modules, Python does that for you and won't `imp` lock anything, aside from the GIL for the sys.modules lookup.

To answer your second edit: I prefer having to maintain a simpler code than trying to optimize calls to the libraries I use (in this case, the standard library). The rationale is that the time required to perform something is usually way more important than the time required to import the module that does it. Furthermore, the time required to maintain this kind of code throughout the project is way higher than the time it will take to execute. It all boils down to: "programmer time is more valuable than CPU time".

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I'm now wondering if the import lock is acquired even when a module has been previously imported (see edit in my original question).

Comment: Edited answer to reflect your edited question. Good point about other Python flavors.

Comment: I stumbled across this part of the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code, which names some more aspects.

Comment: when running python3 multi-threading mode, imported modules are all cached? How can I disable that cache? I know in general cache is good, but is there's a way to turn this off ?? This cache cause phantom read problems in my code.

Comment: @tyan You might be interested by this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898/prevent-python-from-caching-the-imported-modules

Comment: This used to be accurate, but since Python 3.3, import locking has mostly moved to a per-module locking system. The lock control functions in `imp` are deprecated, and holding that lock does not guarantee other threads won't perform imports concurrently.

Comment: Thanks @user2357112supportsMonica , I updated the answer to reflect this update.

Answer (score 2):

I could not find an answer in official documentation on this but it appears that in some versions of CPython 3.x, `__import__` calls are not thread-safe, and can cause a deadlock. See: https://bugs.python.org/issue38884.