# How to use multi-threading to speed up Python imports?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I need to import two modules: A and B. Module A (which will be later used by B) takes too much time to load which slows down the whole code when it's ran sequentially.

Is there a way to import A concurrently *while* B is running in order to speed up the code? The idea being that A would be completely loaded by the time B gets to needing it without the latter having to wait for it.

Thanks.

Comment: For CPython, the GIL will prevent two threads from running concurrently so unless IO is being performed when your modules are imported then multiple threads will probably not help

Comment: Answered on https://stackoverflow.com/a/56388584/8211365

Comment: Yes it does ! Thanks a lot. EDIT: flagged the question as a duplicate.