# Python module not defined in module when using custom load function

Tags: python, python-import

Consider the following program to load all modules in a directory:

```
import pkgutil
import os.path
import sys

def load_all(directory):
    for loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages([directory]):
        loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(here, 'lib')
    sys.path.append(path)
    load_all(path)
```

Now consider that we have the following files.

**lib/magic/imho.py:**

```
"""This is an empty module.
"""
```

**lib/magic/wtf.py:**

```
import magic.imho
print "magic contents:", dir(magic)
```

**lib/magic/__init__.py:**

```
"Empty package init file"
```

When executing the program above, it output:

```
magic contents: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

In other words, despite the `import magic.imho` there is no attribute `imho` on the package `magic` which causes any later references to `magic.imho` to fail.

Running the same code (more or less) directly in python shows a different output, which is the one I expected from running the loading program.

```
$ PYTHONPATH=lib ipython
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import magic.wtf
magic contents: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'imho']
```

Why is there a difference?

**Update:** The point here is that the symbol `magic.imho` does not exist inside `magic.wft` despite the fact that it was explicitly imported. So, what need to be done to the custom load procedure to make it behave correctly and ensure that the symbol *is* visible after it has been imported in `magic.wtf`.

**Solution using `setattr`:** [BartoszKP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2642204/bartoszkp) gave the solution below using an `exec` to assign the value to the package. Since I do not usually like using `exec` (for a lot of reasons, injections is the first one) I used `setattr` and `rpartition` as follows:

```
def load_all(directory):
    for loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages([directory]):
        module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)
        pkg_name, _, mod_name = name.rpartition('.')
        if pkg_name:
           setattr(sys.modules[pkg], mod_name, module)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3365846/2642204) to mimic more accurately what `import` is doing you should modify your `load_all` method as follows:

```
def load_all(directory):
    for loader, name, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages([directory]):
        module = loader.find_module(name).load_module(name)
        exec('%s = module' % name)
```

This way it works, and *wtf.py* will have the name properly bounded inside `magic`. So next time `magic` is imported it won't be reloaded (because this function puts it in `sys.modules` already) but it will have all its submodules properly assigned.

This seems to alleviate some quirk in `import` mechanisms, which I've tried to diagnose below.

---

The difference effectively comes from the the fact that in the first case modules are loaded in a different order than in the second case. When you add `print` statements to each module you'll see the following when executing the main script:

> loading magic
>
> loading imho
>
> loading wtf
>
> magic contents: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']

For the second case:

> loading magic
>
> loading wtf
>
> loading imho
>
> magic contents: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'imho']

So, in the first case `magic` and `imho` are already loaded when *wtf.py* executes, and the [`import`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statements doesn't reload already loaded modules:

> First, if the module already exists in sys.modules (a possibility if the loader is called outside of the import machinery) then it is to use that module for initialization and not a new module

If you change your main script like this for example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(here, 'lib')
    sys.path.append(path)
    import magic.wtf
```

It works exactly the same as from the interpreter.

Your original script will also work as intended if you modify *wtf.py* as follows (for the purpose of demonstration):

```
import sys

try:
    del sys.modules['magic.imho']
except:
    pass

import magic.imho

print "magic contents:", dir(magic)
```

or like this:

```
import sys
import magic.imho
magic.imho = sys.modules['magic.imho']

print "magic contents:", dir(magic)
```

Output:

> loading magic
>
> loading imho
>
> loading wtf
>
> loading imho
>
> magic contents: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'imho']

**Note:** a module exists in `sys.modules` if it's *loaded* and that's different from being *imported*. In first case it's *loaded*, but was not imported. So it exists in `sys.modules` but not in current namespace. So I'm guessing that it was loaded by your loader without `imho` bound to it (so it's just bare `magic` module). Afterwards when Python sees `import magic.imho` it checks that `magic` and `magic.imho` are already loaded (can be verified by `print sys.modules`) and takes this version of `magic` and binds it to local variable `magic`.

---

Related:

- [Realoading Python modules](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/notes/reloading.html)
- [Traps for the Unwary in Python’s Import System](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html)  (you shouldn't add local packages to `sys.path`)
- [Prevent Python from caching the imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898/prevent-python-from-caching-the-imported-modules)