# Stop Python3 creating module cache in system directory

Tags: unix, python-3.x, sudo

In [Question 2918898](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898), users discussed how to avoid caching because
modules were changing, and solutions focused on reloading. My question is
somewhat different; I want to avoid caching in the first place.

My application runs on Un*x and lives in `/usr/local`. It imports a
module with some shared code used by this application and another.
It's normally run as an ordinary user, and Python doesn't cache the
module in that case, because it doesn't have write permission for that
system directory. All good so far.

However, I sometimes need to run the application as superuser, and then
it does have write permission and it does cache it, leaving unsightly
footprints in a system directory. Do not want.

So ... any way to tell CPython 3.2 (or later, I'm willing to upgrade)
not to cache the module? Or some other way to solve the problem?
Changing the directory permissions doesn't work; root can still write,
root is all-powerful.

I looked through [PEP 3147](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) but didn't see a way to prevent caching.

I don't recall any way to import code other than `import`. I suppose I
could read a simple text file and `exec` it, but that seems inelegant
and bug-prone.

The run-as-root is accomplished by calling the program with `sudo` in a
shell script, and I can have the shell script delete the cache after the
run, but I'm hoping for something more elegant that doesn't change the
directory's last-modified timestamp.

---

Implemented solution, based on Wander Nauta's answer:

Since I run the executable as a plain filename, not as `python executablename`, I went with the environment variable. First, the
`sudoers` file needs to be changed to allow setting environment
variables:

```
tom     ALL=(ALL) SETENV: NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bkup/bin/mkbkup
```

Then, the invocation needs to include the variable:

```
/usr/bin/sudo PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true /usr/local/bkup/bin/mkbkup "$@"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154443/how-to-avoid-pyc-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start python with the `-B` command-line flag to prevent it from writing cached bytecode.

```
$ ls
bar.py  foo.py
$ cat foo.py 
import bar
$ python -B foo.py; ls
bar.py  foo.py
$ python foo.py; ls
bar.py  foo.py  __pycache__
```

Setting the `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE` environment variable to a non-empty string or the `sys.dont_write_bytecode` to True will have the same effect.

Of course, I'd say that the benefits in this case (faster loading times for your app, for free) vastly outweigh the perceived unsightliness you were talking about - but if you really want to disable caching, here's how.

Source: [man python](http://linux.die.net/man/1/python)

Comment: Ah, I wish you'd posted the `sys.dont_write_bytecode` a little earlier. Would have spared me struggling with how to make `sudo` accept an environment variable. It works now. Will post details of what I did in the question for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: I'm more worried about cache related bugs, personally. It might not happen often, but when it turns out that my "bug" is actually an outdated cache being loaded, it's miserable. That said--I think I'd rather write all the cache to a local dir that I can just obliterate, if I suspect a cache issue (as opposed to not writing cache at all)