# In the Python REPL, how to get latest code from all file?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I have the following toy code in two files:

File `b.py`:

```
def test_b():
    print "b"
```

File `a.py`:
    from b import test_b

```
def test_a():
    print "a"
    test_b()
```

Then I run the python REPL:

```
>>> execfile("a.py")
>>> test_a()
a
b
```

Then I modify `b.py` into:
    def test_b():
        print "bb"

And run in the REPL:

```
>>> execfile("b.py")
>>> test_a()
a
bb
```

For now it is all fine. Now I modify `a.py` into:

```
from b import test_b

def test_a():
    print "aa"
    test_b()
```

Now I run into the REPL:

```
>>> execfile("a.py")
>>> test_a()
aa
b
```

Which is not fine anymore since the REPL got the older version of `b.py`. Python seems to be doing some caching when loading the files, and my question is: is there a way to force it not to do that? I couldn't find a proper option for the function `excefile`.

Comment: Is this answer helpful to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2918951/758446

Comment: @BlackVegetable looks like it, thanks. I am about to test it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: 
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html
you can use reload(a) (it must have been imported once before). See the description, it might not be the best solution.

The citation:

> Note
>
> For efficiency reasons, each module is only imported once per interpreter session. Therefore, if you change your modules, you must restart the interpreter – or, if it’s just one module you want to test interactively, use reload(), e.g. reload(modulename).

and the description of the function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload
to use with moderation since:

> If a module imports objects from another module using from ... import ..., calling reload() for the other module does not redefine the objects imported from it — one way around this is to re-execute the from statement, another is to use import and qualified names (module.*name*) instead.

The simplest solution is restarting your interpreter.