# Importing a function from a module fails, but classes can be imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a package with several nested modules:

```
somepackage/
  module1/
    __init__.py
    module2/
      __init__.py
      to_be_imported.py
setup.py
```

I have installed this package with `python setup.py develop`. The `to_be_imported.py` file contains a few classes and a method (after the classes, since the method uses some classmethods of the classes). After opening an IPython console, the following import works:

```
from somepackage.module1.module2.to_be_imported import SomeClass
```

but this one fails with ImportError:

```
from somepackage.module1.module2.to_be_imported import my_method
```

Moreover, if I import the file as

```
from somepackage.module1.module2 import to_be_imported
```

and print the imported file content, it prints `my_method` too!

I am confused about what causes the import error, does anybody encountered such problems?

Comment: Are you sure you imported `to_be_imported` inside `module2/__init__.py` with: `from .somepackage.module1.module2.to_be_imported import *`

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the question, forget to add .to_be_imported to the first two imports, my __init__.py files are empty

Answer (score 2):

Note that `module2` is a **misnomer**, as it isn't actually a module but a subpackage.

You have access to `SomeClass` because it has been imported from `to_be_imported` into `module2.__init__.py`. You can open `module2.__init__.py` to confirm this.

To access that function, you should specify the full path:

```
from somepackage.module1.module2.to_be_imported import my_method
```

Or have it imported into `module2.__init__.py` to use the shorter path.

Comment: Please see my updated question, I did use the full path, my question was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, my problem was that my module was cached into my IPython session. I added `my_method` later, so the cached version did not contain it, but when I printed the file, it printed the newest version. More on the topic:
[Prevent Python from caching the imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898/prevent-python-from-caching-the-imported-modules)

To summarize: a console restart is all I needed.