# Python: Measuring time of imports on different machines - difference between first and second run

Tags: python, caching, time, import

I want to measure the time that is required to load packages on different cpus in python (with Pycharm). For that, i wrote this little script:

```
import time
from helper.aux_function import timeit, get_processor_name

modules = ["tensorflow", "torch"]

results = {"cpu":get_processor_name()}

for m in modules:
    @timeit
    def import_module():
        return __import__(m)
    (mod, it) = import_module()
    results[f"{m}_{mod.__version__}"] = "{:.3f}".format(it)

print(results)
```

with

```
def timeit(func):
    """
    Decorator for measuring function's running time.
    """
    def measure_time(*args, **kw):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kw)
        et = time.time() - start_time
        print("Processing time of %s(): %.2f seconds."
                % (func.__qualname__.split(".")[-1], et))

        return result, et

    return measure_time

def get_processor_name():
    if platform.system() == "Linux":
        command = "cat /proc/cpuinfo"
        all_info = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True).strip()
        for line in all_info.decode().split("\n"):
            if "model name" in line:
                return re.sub( ".*model name.*:", "", line,1)
    return ""
```

Running the script the first time after switching to the right interpreter in Pycharm gives me

```
Processing time of import_module(): 9.91 seconds.
Processing time of import_module(): 2.77 seconds.
```

However, running it a second time yields,

```
Processing time of import_module(): 1.08 seconds.
Processing time of import_module(): 0.32 seconds.
```

It seems obvious that there might be some form of caching that causes that second run to speed up - is there any way I can get similar results in both cases, maybe disable caching modules or s.th.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent Python from caching the imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898/prevent-python-from-caching-the-imported-modules)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918898/prevent-python-from-caching-the-imported-modules - this should solve your problem.

Comment: no actually not - for example, when I search for `tensorflow` in `sys.modules.keys()` before any imports . Furthermore, using `importlib.reload` gives the same result

Comment: If `reload` gives same result then try reloading manually. i.e. delete then load again by two separate commands. If that still doesn't work then closing and opening the console is the only option, I think.