# (Maya Python) How do I run radio option buttons through a GUI function?

Tags: python, scripting, radio-button, maya, pymel

Normally when I run a script with radio button options you select a radio button option and then you activate it with the button. I used to leave my menu gui outside of a function: but ever since I learned importing maya scripts I started wrapping my menu interfaces in a GUI function which mean my radio button technique now no longer works. I have no idea how to get it to work either. The script itself is simple enough: just select a radio button option after importing the script and then create a shape with the button: atleast thats how it SHOULD work. Instead I get no errors and no shapes created and I dont know whats broken.

```
'''
import cubeTestTemp
reload (cubeTestTemp)
cubeTestTemp.gui()
'''

import maya.cmds as cmds

#Creates ui. 
if cmds.window("cubeWin", exists =True):
    cmds.deleteUI("cubeWin", window = True)

myWindow = cmds.window("cubeWin",t='DS shapeDemo V1',w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
#Creates variable to indicate the check box status. 1=Checked 0=Not Checked. 

cubeNum1 = 0
cubeNum2 = 0


#Creates Button funtion. 
def defaultButtonPush(*args):
       #The Print checks if button is pushed and what is the check box status. 
       print "Button is pushed."
       print cubeNum1
       #Check box argument finds the status of the variable and determines what to do. 
       #Eather create a cube or display a error dialog box.
       if cubeNum1 == 1:
        print "Cube Creation sucessful"
        cmds.polyCube()

       print "Button is pushed."
       print cubeNum2
       if cubeNum2 == 1:
        print "Sphere Creation sucessful"
        cmds.polySphere()


def gui(*args):
    #Creates check box. 
    #In the onCommand Script (onc) and offCommand Script (ofc) flags all commands must be made in between double quotes.
    cmds.radioCollection()
    cmds.radioButton(label='Cube',align='left',onCommand="cubeNum1 = 1", offCommand="cubeNum1 = 0")
    cmds.radioButton(label='Sphere',align='left',onCommand="cubeNum2 = 1", offCommand="cubeNum2 = 0")
    #Creates Button.
    cmds.button( label='Execute', command=defaultButtonPush ,align='left' )

cmds.showWindow()
```

Comment: instead of lambda in @ababak answer
, you could use partial : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48570602/maya-python-script-works-from-console-doesnt-work-from-file/48579653#48579653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the modified script. The problem was the scope of the scripts. "onCommand" was executed in its own scope that has its own "cubeNum" variables.

```py
"""
import cubeTestTemp
reload (cubeTestTemp)
cubeTestTemp.gui()
"""

import maya.cmds as cmds

# Variable to indicate the radio button status. 1=Cube, 2=Shpere. 
shape_selector = 0


def action_button(*args):
    """
    Create an object based on the shape_selector status
    """
    print "Button is pushed", repr(args)
    if shape_selector == 1:
        cmds.polyCube()
        print "Cube created"
    elif shape_selector == 2:
        cmds.polySphere()
        print "Sphere created"
    else:
        print "No shape selected"


def selection_changed(shape):
    """
    Save the current shape selection
    into global variable "shape_selector"
    """
    global shape_selector
    shape_selector = shape
    print "Current selection:", shape_selector


def gui():
    """
    Create the GUI
    """
    if cmds.window("cubeWin", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("cubeWin", window=True)
    myWindow = cmds.window("cubeWin", t='DS shapeDemo V1', w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
    column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
    # Create the radio buttons 
    cmds.radioCollection()
    cmds.radioButton(label='Cube',align='left', select=True, onCommand=lambda x:selection_changed(1))
    cmds.radioButton(label='Sphere',align='left', onCommand=lambda x:selection_changed(2))
    # Create the push button
    cmds.button(label='Create', command=action_button, align='left')
    cmds.showWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Another way is to read the radio button state only when needed

```py
"""
import cubeTestTemp
reload (cubeTestTemp)
cubeTestTemp.gui()
"""

import maya.cmds as cmds


def action_button(cube_button, sphere_button):
    """
    Create an object based on the shape_selector status
    """
    if cmds.radioButton(cube_button, query=True,select=True):
        cmds.polyCube()
        print "Cube created"
    elif cmds.radioButton(sphere_button, query=True,select=True):
        cmds.polySphere()
        print "Sphere created"
    else:
        print "No shape selected"


def gui():
    """
    Create the GUI
    """
    if cmds.window("cubeWin", exists=True):
        cmds.deleteUI("cubeWin", window=True)
    myWindow = cmds.window("cubeWin", t='DS shapeDemo V1', w=200, h=500, toolbox=True)
    column = cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
    # Create the radio buttons 
    cmds.radioCollection()
    # Save the button ids
    cube_button = cmds.radioButton(label='Cube',align='left', select=True)
    sphere_button = cmds.radioButton(label='Sphere',align='left')
    # Create the push button
    cmds.button(label='Create', command=lambda x:action_button(cube_button, sphere_button), align='left')
    cmds.showWindow()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Comment: Thank you very much ababak, I do have a few more questions though. Let's say I wanted to add a third radio button, is the "if elif" method of coding able to do more radio buttons or does it max out at 2?

Comment: and then my next question is what is "if __name__ == "__main__" what type of coding term is that and what does it do? The comment seems to have edited out the underscores: but I'm talking about the main line beneath the Gui function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: If you are happy with the answer to your original question, you may consider accepting it ;)